# Couldn't the orbits of ETNOs have been altered by a flying-by rogue planet as well?

Tags: solar-system, rogue-planet, trans-neptunian-object

Regarding the [Extreme trans-Neptunian objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_trans-Neptunian_object) or ETNOs, whose orbits some believe are elongated by a far away planet, could their orbits have been elongated by a [rogue planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet) as well? Is it possible that a planet at solar escape velocity performed a path on which it would attract the ETNOs in a similar way, or does the planet need to (still) orbit the Sun to explain the orbits?